# Using PrototypeJs, how to load a jsp page asynchronously

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, templates, prototypejs

We're using Spring and PrototypeJs in our app. Basically I want to have a template page and then fill the template page with some values. I found a JQuery.load method but we're not using JQuery.

Closest thing I found was prototype Template object which is just a string. I can make a template in Javascript like the following:

```
var template1 = new Template("user id: #id name is <span class name='userName'>#name</span>");
```

and then once I have all the data as json fill in the blanks but this is not enough. I want to display tags etc and be more complex and ideally just load this template file once and just fill in the values later. Is that even possible without using backbone.js or angularjs?

I guess my question is, how do I construct a page better? Currently I'm creating my entire page in javascript (e.g. new Element("div").addClassName("something")) so I was hoping to create my page 'template' in a jsp or some other form and then just fill in the blanks.

I have all the data to display on the page as json.

Comment: I won't post an answer because I don't have a library specific solution; but if you have the JSON to construct the page, can you not just run it through your create function?  You'd need to devise your own protocol, perhaps, for page construction, but I don't see why you couldn't do it yourself -- assuming I understand you.

Comment: it "felt wrong". I wanted to put my formatting more clearly and readable in a separate html/jsp type file and just fill it in with data like the template above. I don't have too much experience in this so I am not sure if what I'm doing is right.

Comment: if it works, it works -- it's just someone might have invented a better way :)  Since JSON is human readable and a c-type readable object, you can literally define your "templates" by just writing out JSON -- a lot of nodejs does this, though some people use YAML to make it even more readable.  I don't see a problem with it, if it suits your fancy.

Comment: thank you. it's just difficult sometimes when we need to mix in other custom tags that are not a regular div/span element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Template class is quite flexible about how you create its members. What I would do, for readability, is code your template as an actual page element in the HTML, and then remove it on page load before using it to fill in your JSON.

```
<div id="template-1" class="#{classname}">
  <h1>#{headline}</h1>
  <p>#{description}</p>
</div>
<div id="articles"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var tmp = $('template-1').remove();
tmp.writeAttribute('id',false);
var template = new Template(tmp.outerHTML);
// do whatever with it
$('articles').insert(template.evaluate(myJSON));
</script>
```

That should get you started. The major benefit of working this way is that you don't have to keep backslashing quotes and writing everything in one line, or bashing it together with + signs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think this is a good idea. I can reuse the same template and just loop thru my json data with new values for the same template!

Comment: If you're doing this inside a loop, you can kill two birds by putting your 'You must have JavaScript enabled' message inside the template, and removing it before using the template, just as I removed the ID.